# How do I print a String diagonally from right to left?

Tags: java

I'm practicing some java exercises online and came across one that would print the string "DIAGONALLY" in this way:

> ```
> D
>   I
>     A
>       G 
>         O
>           N 
>             A
>               L
>                 L
>                   Y
> ```

I got that done no problem. Then I decided that I wanted to try and print it out like this:

> ```
> D
>   I
>     A
>       G 
>         O
>           N 
>         A
>       L
>     L
>   Y
> ```

Here's what I had tried so far:

```
public class Examples {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String d = "DIAGONALLY";
        String s = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < d.length(); i++) {
            System.out.printf("%s%s\n", s, d.charAt(i));
            if (i < 6)
                s = s + " ";
            else
                s = s - " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Now obviously the "else s = s - " ";" part is wrong, but I just put that there for now because I do not know how I would subtract an empty space from a string. How would I print the substring of d starting from 6 diagonally from the right to the left?

Comment: The Java string class has a "substring" method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the substring()

```
public String substring(int beginIndex)
```

Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins with the character at the specified index and extends to the end of this string.

And your code have one error that i should less 5

```
public class Examples  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String d = "DIAGONALLY";
        String s = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < d.length(); i++) {
            System.out.printf("%s%s\n", s, d.charAt(i));
            if (i < 5)
                s = s + " ";
            else
                s = s.substring(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot subtract characters from a string, but you can extract a part of a string using the `substring()` method, which takes two parameters: the index of the first character you want to include in your "cut", and the index of the first character *after* the last character you want to include.

<strike>However, in this case, you might be better off generating a new `String` for each line: `new String(' ', x)` will give you a `String` that consists of `x` spaces.</strike> (Sorry, language confusion: that constructor exists in C#, but not in Java.)

For later (when you start writing bigger programs that process larger amounts of data), be aware that string concatenation (`+`) and `substring()` are slower the bigger the string is. If you need to gradually manipulate a large string, you should use a `StringBuffer` or a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Examples {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String d = "DIAGONALLY";
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("");

        for (int i = 0; i < d.length(); i++) {
            System.out.printf("%s%s\n", s, d.charAt(i));
            if (i < (d.length()+1)/2)
                s.append(" ");
            else
                s.setLength(s.length()-1);
        }
    }
}
```

`StringBuilder` is like an expandable `String`. You can add to it with `.append()` as often as you like. You can also set its length. So to do your `s = s - " "`, I'm just setting its length to one less than it was last time.

I've also changed your hardcoded length of 6 to be the half the length of the d string (plus one to get the math to work), so that it will work for any string.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse its not new techinique but different.

```
  String d = "DIAGONALLY";
        String s = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < d.length(); i++) {
           //System.out.printf("%s%s", s, d.charAt(i));
            System.out.println(s+d.charAt(i));
            if (i <6)
                s = s + " ";
            else
                s = s.substring(0,s.lastIndexOf(" "));

        }
```